# Tag user's friends programmatically when sharing on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to tag a user's facebook friends programmatically when sharing using the Facebook Javascript SDK or https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?

Comment: Why? Why would you do that?

Comment: @WizKid Because part of our app involves multiple users that can both have Facebook profiles, so tagging the other user when sharing the link would make sense.

Comment: Automatically tagging people is not allowed

Comment: @WizKid I figured it was. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.